# Passing multiple values to a function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

i have a function looks like this:

```
function foo($value) 
{
    echo "print: '".$value."' "
}
```

I want to pass an array as `$value` because i need to print a variable number of values. How can i pass them? This is what i have done and it doesn't work:

```
function foo($value)
{
    $no = sizeof($value);
    for($i=0;$i<$no;$i++)
    {
        //The if statement here prevents printing a comma at the end
        if($i != ($no-1) ) 

        echo $value[i].", ";

        else echo $value[i]  ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the `if` statement, just use `implode` to join your array up: `implode(", ", $value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. Don't use a loop. All you're doing is spitting out your array as a comma-separated list, so:

```
function foo ($array_of_values) {
   echo implode(',', $array_of_values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forgot the `$` before `i` in the loop while printing it.

```
function foo($value)
{
$no = sizeof($value);
    for($i=0;$i<$no;$i++)
    {
        if($i != ($no-1) )
        echo $value[$i].", ";

        else echo $value[$i]  ;
    }
}
```

And secondly, the better way to do this is, use `implode`

```
function foo($values)
{
    echo implode(',', $values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and check whether $value [is set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
or if you prefer your variant check $no

```
$no = sizeof($value);
if($no === 0) {
  echo "parameter is empty";
  return;
}
```